# NSUserDefaults not updating on Apple Watch

Tags: ios, nsuserdefaults, watchkit

I have added a group to both my iphone target and apple watch target:

[image]

And in my AppDelegate I have this code:

```
  func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    let userDefaults = NSUserDefaults(suiteName: "group.tripicons")
    userDefaults!.setObject("English", forKey: "languageOfCurrentCountry")
    userDefaults!.setObject("English", forKey: "languageOfDevice")
    userDefaults!.synchronize()
    return true
  }
```

However, when it says it's `nil` in my method:

```
class LanguageManager: NSObject {

  ...
  let userDefaults = NSUserDefaults(suiteName: "group.tripicons")

  func watchTranslation(word: String) -> String {
    print(userDefaults?.dictionaryRepresentation())

    // BREAKS HERE
    let language = userDefaults?.objectForKey("languageOfCurrentCountry") as! String // <---- BREAKS HERE
    ...
  }
}
```

The `print` statement prints an object without the key that I'm looking for:

```
Optional(["MSVLoggingMasterSwitchEnabledKey": 0, "AppleKeyboardsExpanded": 1, "AppleLanguages": (
    en
), "AppleLanguagesDidMigrate": 2.1, "NSInterfaceStyle": macintosh, "NSLanguages": (
    en
), "AppleKeyboards": (
    "en_US@hw=US;sw=QWERTY",
    "emoji@sw=Emoji",
    "en_US@hw=US;sw=QWERTY"
)])
```

This is even when I open up the iphone app before I open the apple watch app. Am I missing something?

== UPDATE ==

```
from AppDelegate:
["languageOfCurrentCountry": English, "AppleKeyboards": (
    "en_US@hw=US;sw=QWERTY",
    "emoji@sw=Emoji",
    "en_US@hw=US;sw=QWERTY"
), "AppleKeyboardsExpanded": 1, "AddingEmojiKeybordHandled": 1, "AppleLanguages": (
    "en-US"
), "ApplePasscodeKeyboards": (
    "en_US@hw=US;sw=QWERTY",
    "emoji@sw=Emoji",
    "en_US@hw=US;sw=QWERTY"
), "AppleLocale": en_US, "NSInterfaceStyle": macintosh, "MSVLoggingMasterSwitchEnabledKey": 0, "NSLanguages": (
    "en-US",
    en
), "AppleITunesStoreItemKinds": (
    audiobook,
    "tv-episode",
    booklet,
    software,
    "software-update",
    "itunes-u",
    ringtone,
    "tv-season",
    movie,
    mix,
    wemix,
    song,
    tone,
    artist,
    "podcast-episode",
    podcast,
    eBook,
    document,
    album,
    "music-video"
), "AppleLanguagesDidMigrate": 9.2, "languageOfDevice": English]
```

Comment: Have you tried deleting the apps from the apple watch and iPhone? I believe I had to do that to get things working, although it could have been coincidental.

Comment: let me try that now one sec

Comment: still broken unfortunately

Comment: So to confirm. You added both the containing app's target to the app group as well as the watch kit extension to the same group. They match identically, and are both `on`? Have you tried printing the defaults right after you set them (in the app delegate)?

Comment: yeh i have the app group on for 3 things: the iphone app, the watch app, and the watch extension (not sure what is honestly). i just noticed something odd. when i run just the app in the simulator, the print statement in the `AppDelegate` is run, however, when i run the watch in the simulator, the print statement in `AppDelegate` doesn't print. does the watch simulator not build the iphone app too?

Comment: just updated the question with the print statement from AppDelegate

Answer (score 4):

The exchange of data using `NSUserDefaults` between iPhone and Apple Watch is only available for watchOS 1.

If you are developing for watchOS 2, you should use the `WatchConnectivity` framework. See Apple's documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/WatchConnectivity/Reference/WatchConnectivity_framework/).

Comment: so do i still need app groups anymore? or do i just do something like`WCSession.defaultSession().updateApplicationContext(["languageOfCurrentCountry": "English"])`

Comment: Yeah, you don't need app groups anymore. You'll find some nice tutorials on how to use the framework on the Internet.